# Search regex for Visual Studio

Tags: regex, angularjs

There have a lot of similar questions on SO. But here is another mental exercise I could not figure out.

Here is the search text:

```
<span ng-show="vm.formName.fieldName.$error.required">*</span>
```

Need to replace with just

```
*
```

or

```
<span>*</span>
```

Obviously we want to replace `ng-show="vm.formName.fieldName.$error.required"` with an empty string. I thought some `*` should be used as wildcard for the `ng-show` attribute. But how?

Is it possible to use wildcard `*` to take the place of a string that include quotation marks? And how can we avoid the `*` character in the text from being replaced?

Comment: [Do not use regex to match HTML. Do not use regex to match HTML. Do not use regex to match HTML.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/237955)

Answer (score 3):

`replace(/ng-show="([\s\S]*)"/,'')` should do the trick.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jH5fE4/1

Comment: Thanks. And +1 for using `regex101.com` demo w explanation.

Comment: @Blaise Yes, `regex101.com` can be very handy at times.